# Coupling between external field and internal parts in Ising model

Tags: interactions, ising-model

If we consider the Ising model:

> $$H(\sigma)= - \sum_{ij}J_{ij}\sigma_{i}\sigma_{j} - \mu \sum_{j}h_{j}\sigma_{j} $$

where $h_{j}$ is the external magnetic field. The fields that we have are the $\sigma$'s. My question is: Can we add a term that creates a coupling between the internal part of the Hamiltonian $H_{internal}= - \sum_{ij}J_{ij}\sigma_{i}\sigma_{j}$ and the external part of the Hamiltonian $H_{external}=- \mu \sum_{j}h_{j}\sigma_{j}$? And if yes, then how? I have this question because I know that if I have two fields $\phi$ and $\psi$, then I can have a Hamiltonian like this

> $$H(\phi,\psi)= H_{\phi} + H_{\psi} + H_{\phi\psi} $$

where $H_{\phi}$ means a term that only depends on $\phi$, $H_{\psi}$ means a term that only depends on $\psi$, and $H_{\phi\psi}$ means a term that depends on both $\phi$ and $\psi$. The confusion for me happens because I know in the $H(\phi,\psi)$ Hamiltonian I can make these two fields couple together, but in the Ising model I only have the $\sigma$'s and they simulate two different things: The internal and external processes. Like if I don't know the Hamiltonian of the Ising model, and I would like to come up with a Hamiltonian from scratch, I would write a Hamiltonian that looks like $H(\phi,\psi)$ and claim that the $\phi$ field dictates the internal process, and the $\psi$ field dictates the external process. But then what would the $H_{\phi\psi}$ term be?! I feel that my question stems from a confusion and I would really appreciate some clear explanation about the matter.

Edit: Is the $H_{\phi\psi}$ term equal to $- \mu \sum_{j}h_{j}\sigma_{j}$ since $h_{j}$ and $\sigma_{j}$ are the $\psi$ and $\phi$ fields respectively, and the $H_{\phi}$ term equal to $- \sum_{ij}J_{ij}\sigma_{i}\sigma_{j}$? But now, we are missing the $H_{\psi}$ part of the Hamiltonian. Now the question is why this part is missing in the Ising model? Like does the Ising model only care about the particles; hence there shouldn't be a term for the magnetic field (i.e. $\psi$ alone)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't couple "parts of the Hamiltonian"; you should couple degrees of freedom (i.e., physical quantities that change/evolve under this Hamiltonian). In your example, the only degrees of freedom are the $\sigma$. Your "coupling" term is the $\sigma_i \sigma_j$ terms, which allows different fields (the individual spins) to interact.

Think of it this way. Imagine instead of $\sum_{ij} \sigma_i \sigma_j$ you just had two fields: $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. Then your "arbitrary" Hamiltonian would look like:

$$
H = H_1 + H_2 + H_{12} $$

but this is what you already have if you spelled out your current model:

$$
H = h_1 \sigma_1 + h_2 \sigma_2 + J_{12} \sigma_1 \sigma_2.
$$

In the Ising model, the external magnetic field is not dynamic -- we assume it is a constant imposed by the environment/experimenter (you can break this assumption, but then it's not the Ising model anymore). So even though you might call it a "field" and also call the $\sigma$'s a "field", they are really quite different creatures mathematically. I think overloading this term might lie behind some of your confusion.

Comment: So, if the external magnetic field is dynamic, how would the hamiltonian with two fields ($\sigma_{1}$ and $\sigma_{2}$) look like? Thanks again for the feedback.

Comment: You would need to add an additional term for the energy of the field itself (something like $h^2$), but otherwise all the two-operator combinations are covered already.

Comment: but would it be correct to claim that the term $h_{1}\sigma_{1}$ means that field $\sigma_{1}$ is coupled to the dynamic field $h_{1}$?

Comment: @Guess601 Yes, I'd say so

Comment: This papers might be useful: https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.47.3950